# How to generate a LINQ query that queries all non-null properties from a search page model

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql

I have two models: `TestRecord` and `Part` where a `TestRecord` contains a reference to a `Part`:

```
TestRecord
----
public string TestRecordId
public int PartId <-- foreign key to parts table
public string Name
public string TestType
public virtual Part Part

Part
----
int PartId
string Name
string Description
public virtual ICollection<TestRecord> TestRecords
```

I have a search page that displays an input for each property of a test record including its associated properties such as:

```
@model TestRecord
<!-- From TestRecord -->
<input asp-for="TestType" type="text" />
<!-- From TestRecord.Part assoc. prop -->
<input asp-for="Part.Name" type="text" />
....
And so on...
```

When I post this to my controller to run the query, what is the best way to handle this query? I have 20+ properties which may or may not be filled out on the page that contributes to filter a query to return a `List<TestRecord>`.

If I just had a couple properties to query AND I knew that they were guaranteed to be populated I could do something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public List<TestRecord> Search(TestRecord testRecord){

    List<TestRecord> records = _db.TestRecords
                     .Where(tr => tr.TestType == testRecord.TestType)
                     .Where(tr => tr.Part.Name == testRecord.Part.Name).ToList();

    return records;
}
```

How would I generate a LINQ query, like mentioned above, that queries for all properties from the model that are not null/empty? Is my only option to hard code all properties into my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just do something like this?

```
[HttpPost]
public List<TestRecord> Search(TestRecord testRecord){

    List<TestRecord> records = _db.TestRecords
                 .Where(tr => String.IsNullOrEmpty(testRecord.TestType) ? true : tr.TestType == testRecord.TestType)
                 .Where(tr => String.IsNullOrEmpty(testRecord.Part.Name) ? true : tr.Part.Name == testRecord.Part.Name)
                 //etc...
                 .ToList();

    return records;
}
```

Essentially only filter if the input is there for every field in 1 big query?

Comment: I believe this will be the most concise answer I was looking for. Ideally it would be great to be able to just filter out all the null attributes before generating the the query but I suppose that's just wishful thinking haha. I'll check back in a bit and if there's nothing to be added here, I'll mark this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

The query doesnt have to be one single chain, you can split it up and insert some `if`:

```
var query = _db.TestRecords.AsQueryable();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(testRecord.TestType))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.TestType == testRecord.TestType);
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(testRecord.Part.Name))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Part.Name == testRecord.Part.Name);
}

// or, you can use an intermediate variable before returning to debug
return query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use an extension method like this:

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> that, object notNull, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notNull?.ToString()))
    {
        return that.Where(predicate);
    }

    return that;
}
```

Then you can compose your LINQ query like this:

```cs
return s.Query()
    .Where(onlyStatus, p => p.Status == onlyStatus)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedDate)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one class that has this requirement with only a limited number of properties, say less than 20, I wouldn't bother creating a generic solution for this. Code a `Where` that checks all properties. This has the advantage that if in future someone changes or removes a property your compiler will complain.

A nice solution would be to give your class an extension function:

```
public static bool HasNullProperties(this MyClass x)
{
    return x.Name == null
        && x.Location == null
        && x.OrderSize == null
        ...;
}

public static IEnumerable<MyClass> WhereHasNullProperties(this IEnumerable<MyClass> source)
{
    return source.Where(item => item.HasNullProperties();
}
```

Usage somewhere in a LINQ statement

```
var result = dbContext.MyItems.WhereHasNullProperties()
    .GroupBy(...)
    .Select(...);
```

If you want a full proof solution that works on several classes, consider designing an interface:

```
interface IHasNullProperties
{
    bool HasNullProperties {get;}
}
```

Your LINQ function will be:

```
 public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereHasNullProperties<TSource>(
      this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
      where TSource : IHasNullProperties
{
    return source.Where(item => item.HasNullProperties();
}
```

Finally a relatively slow method would be to use reflection: for any class, get all its get-properties that are nullable and see if any of them has a null value:

```
static bool HasNullPrperties<TSource>(this TSource source)
    where TSource : class
{
     // Take the type of the source, and get all properties of this type
     var result = source.GetType().GetProperties()

         // keep only the readable properties (so you can do GetValue)
         // and those properties that have a nullable type
         .Where(property => property.CanRead 
             && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.Type) != null)

         // for every of this properties, ask the source object for the property value:
        .Select(property => property.GetValue(source))

        // and keep only the properties that have a null value
        .Where(value => value == null);

        // return true if source has any property with a null value
        // = if there is any value left in my sequence
        .Any();
    return result;  
}
```

Comment: Hi Harald, thanks for the extensive answer, so I meant for this to be tagged as a .NET Core question, so use of static probably would be frowned up. What changes here would be needed to convert this in to a service I can inject in to my controller where I run my query?

Comment: The static functions I created are extension methods (google: extension methods demystified). Every standard LINQ function is an extension method (look at the definitions to see this). I wonder how you can use LINQ if you can't use static functions.